# Cannot launch forever process with systemctl

Tags: node.js, express, centos, forever, systemctl

I have a simple Node/Express server running with forever

```
forever start forever_app_config.json
```

My config file looks like this

```
{
    "uid": "myapp",
    "append": true,
    "watch": true,
    "script": "app.js",
    "sourceDir": "/data/projects/myapp"
}
```

and everything works fine. But when trying to add a service (`/usr/lib/systemd/system/mayapp.service`)

```
[Unit]
Description = My Service

[Service]
User = centos
Group = centos
Environment = NODE_ENV=production
Environment = PORT=3333
ExecStart = /usr/bin/forever start /data/projects/myapp/forever_app_config.json
ExecStop = /usr/bin/forever stop myapp

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

it doesnt work for some reason: `sudo systemctl start myapp -l`

```
myapp.service - My Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2018-02-19 11:43:08 UTC; 12min ago
  Process: 26685 ExecStop=/usr/bin/forever stop malcazar (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 26674 ExecStart=/usr/bin/forever start /data/projects/myapp/forever_app_config.json (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 26674 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

and forever logs (`/home/centos/.forever/myapp.log`) show such an error:
`error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL`.

So, what is wrong with my configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by migrating to `pm2` instead of using forever.
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

Answer (score 0):

The weirdest thing is an issue got resolved by reinstalling foreverjs

```
● myapp.service - My Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-02-22 17:37:43 UTC; 4min 17s ago
 Main PID: 8121 (node)
   CGroup: /system.slice/myapp.service
           ├─8121 node /usr/bin/forever /data/projects/myapp/forever_app_config.json
           └─8244 /usr/bin/node /data/projects/myapp/app.js
```

I'm almost sure that it's not the case `sudo npm install forever -g`, but it works for me now, so closing the question.